# Is this conclusion on stone-weierstrass approximation true?

Tags: calculus, analysis, piecewise-continuity, weierstrass-approximation

Prove or disprove that it's possible to approximate
the functions in $C([a,b],\mathbb R) $ uniformly with arbitrary  error $\epsilon$ by functions in the
algebra $\mathcal A$ generated on $[a, b]$ by any nonvanishing strictly monotonic function $\varphi(x)$ .   that is to say, $\bar{\mathcal A}\supset C([a,b],\mathbb R)$

Here we may have discontinious $\varphi (x)$.

I have tried for $\varphi(x)\in C([a,b],\mathbb R)$, since $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism, we can consider $C(\varphi [a,b],\mathbb R)=\{g:f\circ\varphi^{-1}|f\in C([a,b],\mathbb R)\}$ hence we can use the weierstrass approximation to find a polynomial $P_n=Q\circ\varphi^{-1} $ to approximate $f\circ\varphi^{-1}$, then use $Q$ to approximate $f$, and show that $Q=P_n\circ\varphi$ is in our $\mathcal A$. I'm not sure if this is Right.

For discontinious $\varphi(x)$, I can't find a possible solution.

Feel free to give any hints or point out mistakes above.

Comment: Closure in what topology?

Comment: And what have you tried?  Please [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Comment: In metric space with $d(f,g)=\sup |f-g|$

Comment: @Nate Eldredge. The question is edited

Comment: Your approach is kind of confusing: does $f \varphi^{-1}$ mean multiplication or composition?

Comment: Composition of functions, I should write $f\circ \varphi^{-1}$. SORRY.

Comment: Okay.  For the continuous case you can use Stone-Weierstrass directly, since $\varphi$ separates points.  But for the discontinuous case, something like your idea can work.  A hint is that a strictly monotonic function has a continuous left inverse.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge. But the image of $\varphi$ may not be compact for discontinuous $\varphi$, so the stone-weierstrass may not work?

Comment: I get that! we can consider the generized inverse $f^{-1}(y)=\inf(x:f(x)\geq y)$